# If base 2 looks like a square wave, and base 3 looks like this, what does base e look like?

Tags: computability

[image: Base 2...base 3... base e?]

In computing, base 2 is a 0 and a 1 / on and off in a transistor. Base 3 is -1, 0 and 1.

Electronically/in computing how would/could base e be represented visually?

Comment: I'm not sure in what sense base 2 looks like the first picture, and base 3 like second picture.

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant as in a 0 and a 1 - since in computing that's how they're represented (on/off in a transistor), base 3 would be -1, 0, and a 1 or 0,1,2. I just wondered if that's the case in computing, what would base e look like visually in computing

Comment: Since this visual representation is of your invention, only you can answer this question.

Comment: @Yuval Filmus : I think he's after the idea that base-2 is represented using two equally spaced, distinct voltage levels, and base-3 with three equally spaced, distinct voltage levels.

Comment: @The_Sympathizer Yes, that's what I meant to point to